# "Muéstrame cómo hiciste" o "Muéstrame como hiciste"

Tags: ortografía

¿Cuándo lleva tilde "cómo"?

Según entiendo, cuando tiene valor interrogativo o exclamativo. Pero, ¿también cuándo significa "de qué manera"? En particular para el ejemplo del título: ¿lleva o no?

Mi regla rápida es que si significa "how" en Inglés, debe llevar tilde. Pero puedo estar equivocado...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tienes razón. La regla es que `cómo` lleva tilde cuando tiene sentido interrogativo o exclamativo, aunque hay [excepciones a esta regla](http://www.rae.es/consultas/tilde-en-que-cuales-quienes-como-cuan-cuantoaosas-cuando-donde-y-adonde) cuando el adverbio o pronombre relativo introduce una oración subordinada relativa sin antecedente expreso (y se podría escribir con o si tilde).

Yo te diría que en la pregunta del título lo lleva, dado que al usar "Muéstrame" estamos haciendo una pregunta pero sin saber lo que va detrás, es imposible garantizarlo. Por ejemplo

> A: Quieres ver mis nuevos cuadros? He pintado diez nuevos.
>
> B: No tenemos tanto tiempo. **Muéstrame como** tres de ellos y nos vamos.
>
> Muéstrame, como jefe de departamento que eres, la manera en que te responsabilizas del mismo.
>
> Muéstrame como si te fuera la vida en ello las razones que tienes para acusarme de esta manera.
>
> <sub>Añado este ejemplo tras los edits a la pregunta y los comentarios</sub>
>
> Muéstrame **como** si yo fuese nuevo en la oficina **cómo** se preparan esos informes.

No se me ocurren ejemplos mejores ahora mismo (esas frases son algo forzadas) en el que puedas empezar la frase con "Muestrame" y seguir luego con un "[como](http://buscon.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=s3kpSlOhuD6v706948)" que sea adverbio pero no exclamativo o interrogativo.

Básicamente, **Sí, creo que debe llevar tilde**. Casi seguro va a ser una pregunta (un "[cómo](http://buscon.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=NRljHeeb2D6KmUqa9B)" interrogativo), pero no puedes garantizar el 100% de los casos como solo la fórmula "Muestrame + como".

Comment: ¡Gracias! Quería expresar algo como "Muéstrame cómo hiciste.". En ese caso sería correcta la tilde, ¿no?

Comment: @Guido, mientras sea equivalente a "de qué manera" como tu bien dices llevará tilde. Pero todavía puedo "forzarlo un poco a "Muéstrame, como si fuese tonto, cómo haces ese truco de magia. Es que no lo pillo!". Pero lo estoy forzando. La respuesta a tu pregunta es "sí, lleva tilde".

Comment: Muy educativo, ¡gracias!